# Алгоритм для рынка в игре

Tags: c#, алгоритм, разработка-игр

Пытаюсь сделать идейного наследника Game Dev Tycoon на C# и начал с разработки прототипа игры и сразу столкнулся с проблемой, для реализации основных процессов, требуется чтобы при выпуске пользователем игры, она сравнивалась в рейтинге например по продажам за неделю с остальными выпущенными играми, но как написать алгоритм, который имитирует грубо говоря игровой рынок, который через определённые промежутки времени выпускает игры с каким-либо жанром, темой, оценкой, задаёт новые популярные жанры и т.д.

Как мне реализовать простой ИИ или его некое подобие?

Comment: Люди специально изучают матрицы, методы анализа, поиск в глубину-ширину (как база безоговорочно). За 3-ри дня эта задача не делается.

Comment: Не акцентируйтесь на детальной "имитации". Все что игрок не видит должно быть сделано с минимально достаточным реализмом. А уж *как* это работает внутри - никто никогда не узнает. И не забывай, игра в первую очередь должна быть интересной, а не "реалистичной".

Comment: @nick_n_a
Да, понимаю, но в игре предусматривается достаточно линейный сюжет, по этому думаю мне должно хватить базовых знаний, которые имеются сейчас. Но всё равно спасибо за мнение, буду иметь ввиду

Comment: @Kromster Да, понимаю, я не собирался детально прорабатывать подобные вещи, потому что в таком случае разработка затянется на много месяцев, если вообще дойдёт до конца

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можно обойтись несколькими списками или массивами внутри которых будут классы - модели. Внутри них можно хранить коэффициенты вероятностей.

Как то так:

создаёшь список из объектов - моделей игры

создаёшь список из объектов внутри которых записан успех каждого соперника (например предыдущей недели)

рандомом увеличиваешь/изменяешь вероятность выбора из списка конкретного жанра этой недели

рандомом выбираешь жанр этой недели итп.

добавляешь дополнительный коэффициент успешности игр совпадающих по жанру

рандомно увеличиваешь коэффициент создания соперником определённой игры по популярному жанру

вычисляешь успешность соперников

рандомом ставиш успешность своей игры

сравниваешь свою игру со всем списком игр соперников

делишь прибыль по коэффициенту успешности

очишаешь всю историю

повторяешь всё снова